# Two applications need different JDK

Tags: java, java-8, wso2, java-11, elk

I'm running *ELK Stack* on local for R&D to implement Log monitoring for a *wso2 Enterprise Integrator 6.1.0* application.

*ELK Stack* needs open JKD 11 or more. but the wso2 application needs JDK 8. both applications take `JAVA_HOME` in the account for running. How can I run both applications without changing the `JAVA_HOME` after running *ELK* or *wso2 Enterprise Integrator*.

Comment: I think you need to create specific cmd/bat files to launch the applications you desire, each with a different JDK path.

Comment: I did that only but I was wondering if there is any other way to do this

Comment: I had a similar use case in one of my projects and I used `SDKMan` for a while. But later I shifted to the bat/script files as gives you a lot of flexibility. No tool gives us that flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create separate batch files for different JDK versions and whenever you need a different JDK version to work with, Just run the respective bat file.

```
@echo off
echo Setting JAVA_HOME
set JAVA_HOME=C:\j2sdk1.4.2_12
echo setting PATH
set PATH=C:\j2sdk1.4.2_12\bin;%PATH%
echo Display java version
java -version
```

**Note** :

1. Assign JAVA_HOME value in batch files, according to your Java installation.
2. JAVA_HOME and path to java must always refer to the exact same version of the JDK.

Comment: I know this is there any other way to do that.